# How to increase procedure cache ratio hit ratio?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I have a server with 96 GB of RAM that has the Buffer Cache Hit Ratio consistently at 100% , so memory is obviously not a problem.
**I am using sql-server 2014**

Comment: go through this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57313/how-to-improve-procedure-cache-hit-ratio

Comment: I haven't get idea from this link is there any other resource available ?

Comment: what's your actual problem? Not your perceived solution to your problem.....

Comment: I am monitoring my database through a tool named as DATABASE PERFORMANCE ANALYSER(by solarwinds) from there i got to know about low procedure cache hit ratio is there in my  instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat sir,i have 100% **BUFFER CACHE HIT RATIO** my **PROCEDURE CACHE HIT RATIO ** is low